# FBRequestConnection not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, cocoa, facebook-ios-sdk

Nothing gets printed out in the console, and I don't get any info while using a `- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result` either

Basically I would like the **user's name, FB username, and FB id**. Is there any other way to get this info, since this method does not seem to be working.

```
- (IBAction)performLogin:(id)sender
{
    [self.spinner startAnimating];

    GIFAppDelegate* appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    [appDelegate openSession];
    FBRequestConnection* conn = [[FBRequestConnection alloc] init];
    [conn addRequest:[FBRequest requestForMe] completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *me, NSError *error) {
        if(error) {
            NSLog(@"Error requesting user info");
            return;
        }

        NSLog(@"User's name is %@", me.name);
    }];
}
```

Note that the rest of the method works, just not the FBRequestConnection portion of it. :)

Answer (score 3):

I believe you have just started using the new graph SDK:

Here is how you can pull out some of the info:

// Your Info:

```
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/me" parameters:nil HTTPMethod:@"GET" completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"result %@",result);
}];
```

// Your Friends Info

```
   [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/friends" parameters:nil HTTPMethod:@"GET" completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"result %@",result);
    }];
```

And similarly, you can pull out more information. You should read about more graph objects - [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/). This is how you will get to know, what all things you can pull out. Also you can query on facebook using FQL.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This code does not work for me for some reason. Output: Error: HTTP status code: 400 result(null)

Comment: Actually I found out how to get it to work - I put it in the openSession method. Congratulations! Here, please reward yourself to a chocolate chip cookie!

Comment: Actually this method is still glitchy, do you know why it is so glitchy - it work only 70% of the time, that really isn't good enough. :(  I know it's not ur fault, it's FB's but is there a way to get 100% accuracy.

Comment: If Graph is not working alright for you then try to read about 'FQL' and FBRequests with FQL.

Comment: it is working fine but, data is nil ,data =     (
    );

Answer (score 2):

Add the following line after adding the request:

```
[conn start];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableDictionary* params =   [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                 [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)10], @"score",
                                 nil];


dispatch_queue_t some_queue = dispatch_queue_create("some.queue.name", NULL);

dispatch_async(some_queue, ^{

    // [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%llu/scores", lintFBFriendId]

    [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"APP_ID/scores"
                                 parameters:params
                                 HTTPMethod:@"GET"
                          completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result,     NSError *error)
     {
         NSLog(@"result->%@");
     }
     }];
```

I wanna Fetch Scores but when i put `[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:` in a queue but it doesn't response or print data if i remove queue it works

code ->